# Freetype рисует только красный цвет

Tags: c++, opengl

Имею вот такой FontRenderer:

```cpp
FontRenderer::FontRenderer(ResourceLocation fontLocation, int size) {
    FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
    FT_New_Face(ft, fontLocation.GetFilePath().c_str(), 0, &face);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, size*2);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    FT_GlyphSlot slot = face->glyph;

    for (GLubyte character = 0; character < 128; character++) {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, character, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            continue;
        
        GLuint textureID;
        glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, slot->bitmap.width, slot->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, slot->bitmap.buffer);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        GLfloat x2 = slot->bitmap_left;
        GLfloat y2 = slot->bitmap_top;
        GLfloat w = slot->bitmap.width;
        GLfloat h = slot->bitmap.rows;

        Glyph glyph = {
            textureID,
            x2, y2,
            w, h,
            slot->advance.x, slot->advance.y
        };
        glyphs[character] = glyph;
    }

    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
}

void FontRenderer::DrawString(const string& text, float x, float y, int color) {
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(x, y+20, 0);
    glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glColor4f((color >> 16 & 255) / 255.0f, (color >> 8 & 255) / 255.0f, (color >> 24 & 255) / 255.0f, (color & 255) / 255.0f);

    std::string::const_iterator character;
    for (character = text.begin(); character != text.end(); character++) {
        Glyph glyph = glyphs[*character];
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glyph.textureID);

        GLfloat x2 = x + glyph.x;
        GLfloat y2 = -y - glyph.y;
        GLfloat w = glyph.width;
        GLfloat h = glyph.height;

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(x2, y2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(x2, y2 + h);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(x2 + w, y2 + h);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(x2 + w, y2);
        glEnd();

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        x += glyph.advanceX >> 6;
        y += glyph.advanceY >> 6;
    }
}
```

Отрисовывается отлично, но текст красный.

Comment: `GL_RED` при создании текстуры как бы намекает

Comment: @user7860670 я знаю, но замена на GL_ALPHA GL_RGB и GL_RGBA не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Вот фикс:

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, slot->bitmap.width, slot->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, slot->bitmap.buffer);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```